Sequence $x_n \rightarrow 0$ : Can we find a rational sequence $r_n \rightarrow+\infty$ such that $x_n r_n \rightarrow 0$?
Let $x_n$ be a sequence such that $x_n \rightarrow 0$.
Is it possible to find a rational sequence $r_n \rightarrow+\infty$ such that $x_n r_n \rightarrow 0$ ?
Here is a proposed construction for $r_n$ :
$$
r_n= \begin{cases}\left\lfloor 1 / \sqrt{\left|x_n\right|}\right\rfloor & \text { if } x_n \neq 0 \\ n & \text { if } x_n=0\end{cases}
$$
With this definition, $r_n$ is rational and $r_n \rightarrow+\infty$. Additionally, it can be verified that $x_n r_n \rightarrow 0$ holds under this construction.
Does this construction seem correct, or are there other possible ways to define $r_n$, especially in the case where $x_n=0$ for infinitely many terms?

Yes it is correct. Another way would be to take $r_n=0$ for all $n$ :-)

@StefanLafon: That does not satisfy $r_n \to +\infty$

Ooops yes, indeed :-) Merry Christmas!

It is correct. But $r_n$ without floor function also works right?

@NagaSaiPrajith OP wants it to be rational

The following construction  (from Rudin, W., Functional Analysis, 2nd edition, McGraw-Hill, pp. 22) works for sequences $x_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\boldsymbol{0}$ in  a topological vector space whose topology is generated by translation invariant metric.
Choose a strictly monotone increasing sequence $(m_k:k\in\mathbb{N})\subset\mathbb{Z}_+$ such that  $m_0=0$ and for $k\geq1$, $d(x_n,\boldsymbol{0})<\frac1{k^2}$ for all $n\geq m_k$. Define the sequence $r_n$ by setting
$r_n=0$ if $n<m_1$ and  $r_n=k$ if $m_k\leq n< m_{k+1}$.
By construction, $(r_n:n\in\mathbb{N})\subset\mathbb{N}_+$ and $\lim_nr_n=\infty$. Notice that  if $n\in[m_k,m_{k+1})$,
$$d(r_nx_n,\boldsymbol{0})\leq r_n d(x_n,\boldsymbol{0})\leq \frac{1}{k}$$
Form this, it follows that
$r_nx_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\boldsymbol{0}$.

Can we express $k$ as a function of $n$ to highlight that $k$ tends to $+\infty$ as $n$ tends to $+\infty$ ?

You can write $r_n=\sum^\infty_{k=0}k\mathbb{1}{[m_k,m{k+1})}(n)=\inf{k\in\mathbb{Z}_+: m_k\leq n}$
